# Issues in running SSIS package over multiple server hops

Tags: ssis, unc

I am new to SSIS and am facing an issue with reading a File from a remote server

1. I have a Flat File Connection defined at the Project level where the `ConnectionString` is defined by a variable say `@AbsoluteFilePath`.
2. The value of `@AbsoluteFilePath` is calculated at run-time to a UNC say :

   `\\myserver\myfolder\myfile.txt`
3. I have a Web Application which invokes execution of the package.
4. I am able to view the file folder as a logged in user however the execution of the package ends in an error while reading the file.

   The execution fails with error message of `return code 0XC020200E`
5. I tried mapping my UNC `\\myserver\myfolder` to `Z:` on the machine where SQL 2012 is running. However this too gives me the same error.

Is using UNC advisible in SSIS ? What is the standard way of doing this task ?

Following is the complete workflow I am trying to achieve :

> **Complete Picture**
>
> User picks a file on the web front end. the web application saves the
>   file at a shared drive and invokes the SSIS package to run. the SSIS
>   package reads the file from the shared drive and performs required
>   action it.

**Update : Explaining Permissions and running SSIS package from stored procedure**

1. Web Application X runs on a server ***server-web***
2. SSIS package Y runs on a server ***server-ssis***

   1. accesses database on a server ***server-database***
   2. accesses UNC where on a server ***server-filesystem***

The package is being run by executing a stored procedure by running a stored procedures mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878099.aspx

the connection string used by ***server-web***  is of the form

```
Data Source=server-ssis;Initial Catalog=SSISDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: I have run into issues where admins have assigned full control to a folder for our SSIS service account but not to the actual share. Sharing tab, Advanced Sharing, Permissions, Add. That make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet dollars to dumplin's this is a permissions issue (besides the fact a search for `0XC020200E` yields hits on file permissions).

Check the permissions for the account that is running the web application. It needs to be granted permissions to the share. It works with your account or the logged in user but that is probably *not* the same account that is running the package.

Comment: I updated my question giving details of permissions I have. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Put your package in an SQL Agent job and try to execute it. If this works, try executing the SQL job rather than calling the package directly.

Comment: @user1826905 The only challenge with that approach is the job will run asynchronously and the calling web app might need to wait until it finishes, listen for error events, etc.

Comment: This raises a design question. The user picks a file from front end. His action is complete here. But the web application is saving the file to a shared location. At this point the web applications involvement should be complete. By **decoupling the SSIS job** from the Web Application and the User Input and making it a background process, it improves the robustness of the entire process. The web application can always query the SQL Agent job table to find out whats the status of the job.

Comment: @user1826905 you were right. My team ended up using a SQL Agent Job to invoke the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

@user1826905 you were right, using a SQL Agent Job to invoke the SSIS package proved to be the simplest way of invoking the SSIS package from a web application.

This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx gives out two different way of invoking SSIS packages

1. using SQL Agent Job
2. using a web service

There is a third way of invoking SSIS which I was trying using stored procedures http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878099.aspx but has an issue when working across multiple server hops kerberos delegation explained [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/767088/with-the-new-ability-to-execute-ssis-packages-from-tsql-kerberos-delegation-should-be-supported)

We are still struggling over using this approach to access the UNC due to accessing changing to *Anonymous user* after the hop